# Making Sharepoint 2010 Accesible On Internet Using SBS 2011

Tags: sharepoint-2010, windows-sbs

I did a deep search over internet and watched videos. There is nowhere that I could find how to make Sharepoint 2010 accesible from internet using SBS 2011.

What could be the steps to do this?

i.e : sharepoint 2010 is running properly on intranet. But the users want to reach it from home as well. And we are using SBS 2011 including Active Directory. How will these users reach sharepoint from home or not only from intranet?

Would you direct me ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess best solution is to provide VPN access to users. -  future proof and you don't have to tweak any thing to the server. Its cheaper as well considering the cost and they will have seamless integration to AD
2. Next since you have already have AD configured ( it depends on how it has been setup) you could have additional ADFS configuration to authorise users.
3. See if you can upgrade to Windows Server 2012 essentials which gives more power than SBS 11 in terms of Claims authentication
4. Finally, you have to use Claim Based Authentication for the authentication and DNS routing etc which you might have seen on the videos.
5. Finally, you have cloud think Azure as well as an option.

Although I haven't configured SBS 2011 for SharePoint extranet, It appears to be same like windows 2008 server (slim down one) according to MSDN which should not affect your requirement. Apart from licensing... ( check this).

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations, but the Employer doesnt want to use VPN. I had already suggested it. I will insist once again but very less possible to use it...

Comment: Not a recommended option but if security is not that much of a issue check something called Dynamic dns in google where you can host a site in premise. You can use the same principle for the users to access the SharePoint. cheap but cost of security. Only thing is Users have to login using <domain>\<username> with password. Perhaps  you can buy an SSL Certificate for Sharepoint